# How is it possible to run the sound of a push notification in loop?

Tags: android, ios, ionic2

I am developing an app based on Ionic2 framework, I would to know if it's possible to run the sound of a push notification in loop. (i.e. like the VOIP app when you receive a call, the sound keeps repeating..)

So far, I have something like this, which is working fine:

```
           let push = Push.init({
           android: {
               senderID: "idIsHere"
           },
           ios: {
               alert: "true",
               badge: false,
               sound: "true"
           }
       });
```

But, I would like to make the sound of the push notification repeat, any idea?

Comment: On iOS you are now limited too 30 sec max. In iOS 10 you can use the special VOIP telephony API/

Comment: So, far how these VOIP app, such as Viber, IMO, etc... run the sound repeatedly on iOS?

Comment: Have looks at PushKit: https://developer.apple.com/reference/pushkit